# How to find repetitive characters in a string. BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery

I need to identify if a character repeat itself more than 4 times Ina string.
It seems that Regexp_contains should do the job, but for some reason it does not identify this values as containing repeated characters : `'ART00000000'`.

Thank you in advance.

The code I am using :

```
Regexp_contains(Id, r'(.)\\1{3,}')
```

Comment: you mean a character repeats itself more than 4 times in a row ?   Unfortunately, Bigquery regexp functions uses [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) which doesn't support backreference.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/76578957/5221944 for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this can easily be done with a regex in Big Query. As an alternative, we could [`split`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split) the string to an array of characters, and then search for duplicates.

This gives you all `id`s that have at least one character that appears at least 4 times:

```
select id
from mytable
where exists (
    select 1
    from unnest(split(id, '')) as c
    group by c
    having count(*) >= 4
)
```