# BigQuery SQL: - Identify identical digits in a row in a string

Tags: sql, regex, string, google-bigquery

I want to identify when a string has the same digit more than 4 times in a row using SQL Bigquery. Example:

```
AAAAAB - true
BBBBAA - false
111111 - true
01010101010101 - false
```

I've tried so far different approaches with regex, but none with good results.

```
regexp_contains(mycolumn,r'[0-9]\\1{4}') --- gives me false as an output
regexp_contains(mycolumn,r'(\d)*(\d){4}')  --- returns true to every string as long it has more than 4 digits
REGEXP_CONTAINS(mycolumn, '')), r'(\d)1{4}') --same
regexp_contains(mycolumn,r'(\d){4}')`
```

I know I can use `CASE` or `SUBSTRING`, but if I could find a nicer solution without having 10 lines of code to a **"simple"** issue it would be ideal.

Thank you everyone for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The `\1` *[back-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages)* is used to reference a capture group—place the `[0-9]` within parentheses, `( )`.

Additionally, for a *[raw string literal](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#quoted_literals)*, `r''`, you won't need to escape the value—the additional `\` will produce a pattern with a literal `\` character in it.

> *"... I want to identify when a string has the same digit more than 4 times ..."*

```
([0-9])\1{4}
```

On a final note, you have mentioned that *AAAAAB* should be true.

You can add an `A-Z` range to the *character class*.

```
([0-9A-Z])\1{4}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input. It won't work - it is because some particularity of BQ:

'regexp_contains('111111',r'([0-9])\\1{4}')  t1'

returns false

Comment: @Newton, use a single `\\`, not 2.  _([0-9])\1{4}_

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT mycolumn, MAX(size) > 4 AS result
FROM (
  SELECT mycolumn, COUNT(*) size
  FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNTIF(new_group) OVER(PARTITION BY mycolumn ORDER BY OFFSET) AS group_num,
    FROM (
      SELECT *, IFNULL(x != LAG(x) OVER(PARTITION BY mycolumn ORDER BY OFFSET), TRUE) new_group,
      FROM (
        SELECT mycolumn, OFFSET, x
        FROM your_table, UNNEST(SPLIT(mycolumn, '')) x WITH OFFSET
      )
    )
  )
  GROUP BY mycolumn, group_num
)
GROUP BY mycolumn
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After giving first answer - went to the bed and while sleeping got the better solution - see below (still for BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT mycolumn, 
  LOGICAL_OR(REGEXP_CONTAINS(mycolumn, r'' || x || '{5,}')) AS result
FROM your_table, UNNEST(SPLIT(mycolumn, '')) x
GROUP BY mycolumn
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

P.S. I used below for testing

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT 'AAAAAB' AS mycolumn UNION ALL
  SELECT 'BBBBAA' UNION ALL
  SELECT '111111' UNION ALL
  SELECT '01010101010101'
)
SELECT mycolumn, LOGICAL_OR(REGEXP_CONTAINS(mycolumn, r'' || x || '{5,}')) AS result
FROM your_table, UNNEST(SPLIT(mycolumn, '')) x
GROUP BY mycolumn
```

P.S.2

in case you have long strings - use below optimized version

```
SELECT mycolumn, 
  LOGICAL_OR(REGEXP_CONTAINS(mycolumn, r'' || x || '{5,}')) AS result
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT mycolumn, x
  FROM your_table, UNNEST(SPLIT(mycolumn, '')) x
)
GROUP BY mycolumn
```